# Mysql (conditional?) query from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, yii

Not sure if I have phrased the title properly, but here it goes. I have these two tables:

table:staff

```
id      Name        groupId     Status
1       John Smith      1           1
2       John Doe        1           1   
3       Jane Smith      2           1
4       Jerry Smith     1           1
```

table:jobqueue

```
id      job_id  staff_id        jobStatus
1       1       1           1
2       2       1           1   
3       5       2           1
4       7       3           0
```

Now, what I need to do is to find the staff with the least amount of job assigned to him which I am able to do by querying the jobqueue table.

```
SELECT min(cstaff),tmp.staff_id FROM (SELECT t.staff_id, count(staff_id) cstaff from jobqueue t join staff s on t.staff_id=s.id join group g on s.groupId=g.id where g.id=26 GROUP BY t.id ) tmp
```

This works fine, but the problem is if a staff is not assigned to any job at all, this query wont get them, because it only queries the jobqueue table, where that particular staff won't have any entry. I need to modify the query to include the staff table and if a staff is not assigned any job in the jobqueue then I need to get the staff details from the staff table. Basically, I need to find staff for a group who are not assigned any job and if all staffs are assigned job then find staff with the least amount of jobs assigned. Could use some help with this. Also, tagging as Yii as I would like to know if this is doable with Yii active-records. But I am okay with a plain sql query that will work with Yii sql commands.

Comment: your description is kind of confusing but maybe left join?

Comment: what if several users has no jobs in one group? what result do you expect in this case?

Comment: @Ilya Bursov , return the first staff found with no jobs in the group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure that it is optimal query, but it works:

```
select d.groupId, d.name, (select count(*) from jobqueue as e where e.staff_id=d.id) as jobassigned
from staff as d
where d.id in (
    select 
        (
        select a.id
        from staff as a
        left outer join
        jobqueue as b
        on (a.id = b.staff_id)
        where a.groupId = c.groupId
        group by a.id
        order by count(distinct job_id) asc
        limit 1
        ) as notassigneduserid
    from (
        select distinct groupId from staff
    ) as c)
```

maybe need some comments:

`c` query is needed to get all distinct groupId - if you have separate table for this, you can replace it

`notassigneduserid` statement for each groupId select user with minimal job count

`d` query is needed to fetch actual user names, groupId for all found "unassigned users" and present it

here is the results for data from question:

```
Group   Staff           Jobs assigned
1       Jerry Smith     0
2       Jane Smith      1
```

Comment: I am wondering what this gives you when you have two staff that have the same minimum job count?

Comment: @jmarkmurphy it will give you only 1, as it has `limit 1`, but which one is full depends on internals of mysql

Answer (score 1):

```
with 
counts as (
   select s.groupId
      , s.id 
      , (select count(*) from jobqueue where staff_id = s.id) count
   from staff s
   group by s.id, s.groupId),
groups as (
   select groupId, min(count) mincount
   from counts
   group by groupId)
select c.groupId, c.id, c.count
from counts c
join groups g on c.groupId = g.groupId
where c.count = g.mincount
```

This SQL will give you all the staff with the minimum number of jobs in each group.  It might be that more than one staff has the same minimum number of jobs.  The approach is to use common table expressions to build first a list of counts, and then to retrieve the minimum count for each group.  Finally I join the counts and groups tables and retrieve the staff that have the minimum count for each group.

I tested this on SQL Server, but the syntax should work for MySQL as well.  To your data I added:

```
id      Name        groupId     Status
5       Bubba Jones 2           1
6       Bubba Smith 1           1
```

and

```
id      job_id  staff_id        jobStatus
5       4       5               1
```

Results are

```
group    name          count
1        Bubba Smith   0
1        Jerry Smith   0
2        Bubba Jones   1
2        Jane Smith    1
```

BTW, I would not try to do this with active record, it is far too complex.

Answer (score 0):

As Ilya Bursov said this answer wasn't respond exactly what was asked. So here is a more optimized solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT s.id as id_staff, s.Name, s.groupId, count(distinct t.id) as jobsXstaff
  FROM staff s
  LEFT JOIN jobqueue t ON s.id=t.staff_id
  GROUP BY s.id, s.groupId
  ORDER BY s.groupId, jobsXstaff
) tmp
GROUP BY groupId
```

Old answer below.

This works but without table group which I don't create. You can simply join table groups as you did:

```
SELECT min(cstaff),tmp.id
FROM (
  SELECT s.id, count( staff_id ) cstaff
  FROM jobqueue t
  RIGHT JOIN staff s ON t.staff_id = s.id
  GROUP BY t.id
) tmp
```

As you see you need to get all values from table staff (right join) and select the id staff from it's own table (s.id instead of t.staff_id). Also you have to get tmp.id instead of staff_id now.

Comment: you just display all users with job count, it is not what OP asked